# Divide Foreach into threads sample

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, foreach, asp.net-3.5

I want to run "`SearchResultByOrderNumber(string orderNumber)`" method in `Foreach` with multithreading. There are ten OrderNumbers in `OrderNumbers` Datatable. While searching these OrderNumbers in `OrderResults` Datatable, I want to divide these OrderNumbers into five threads. In each thread there will be two search for OrderNumbers. How can I do this threading with Asp.Net 3.5 Framework ?

I think, I must renew my question.
How can I divide "OrderNumbers" into Async methods automatically?
Firstly, I got `rowCount`. I am going to define Async method count. Then I will get `rowsPerAsyncMethods` by division of `rowCount` with `asyncMethodCount`.

```
rowsPerAsyncMethods = rowCount / asyncMethodCount
```

Thank you.

```
void Main()
{   

    var MyTask1Caller = new Func<DataTable>(MyTask1);
    var asyncResultMyTask1 = MyTask1Caller.BeginInvoke(null, null);
    var MyTask2Caller = new Func<DataTable>(MyTask2);
    var asyncResultMyTask2 = MyTask2Caller.BeginInvoke(null, null);

    DataTable dtMyTask1 = MyTask1Caller.EndInvoke(asyncResultMyTask1);
    DataTable dtMyTask2 = MyTask2Caller.EndInvoke(asyncResultMyTask2);
    Console.WriteLine("dtMyTask1");
    Console.WriteLine("dtMyTask2");
    asyncResultMyTask1.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
    asyncResultMyTask2.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();


}

public int RowCount()
{
    DataTable dt = OrderNumbers();
    int items = dt.Rows.Count;

    return items;

}


public DataTable MyTask1()
{
    DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
    DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("OrderNumber", typeof(System.Int32));
    dtResult.Columns.Add(dc);
    dc = new DataColumn("OrderResult", typeof(string));
    dtResult.Columns.Add(dc);

    DataTable dtOrders = new DataTable();
    dtOrders = OrderNumbers();

    var items = dtOrders.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(n => n).Take(3).CopyToDataTable();

    foreach(var order in items.AsEnumerable())
    {   

        string orderNumber = order["OrderNumber"].ToString();
        string orderResult = SearchResultByOrderNumber(orderNumber);
        DataRow dr = dtResult.NewRow();
        dr["OrderNumber"] = orderNumber;
        dr["OrderResult"] = orderResult;
        dtResult.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    //Thread.Sleep(5000);       
    return dtResult;
}


public DataTable MyTask2()
{
    DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
    DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("OrderNumber", typeof(System.Int32));
    dtResult.Columns.Add(dc);
    dc = new DataColumn("OrderResult", typeof(string));
    dtResult.Columns.Add(dc);

    DataTable dtOrders = new DataTable();
    dtOrders = OrderNumbers();

    var items = dtOrders.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(n => n).Skip(3).Take(3).CopyToDataTable();

    foreach(var order in items.AsEnumerable())
    {   

        string orderNumber = order["OrderNumber"].ToString();
        string orderResult = SearchResultByOrderNumber(orderNumber);
        DataRow dr = dtResult.NewRow();
        dr["OrderNumber"] = orderNumber;
        dr["OrderResult"] = orderResult;
        dtResult.Rows.Add(dr);
    }


    return dtResult;
}

    public string SearchResultByOrderNumber(string orderNumber)
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = OrderResults();

        var query = (from n in dt.AsEnumerable()
                    where n["OrderNumber"].ToString() ==orderNumber
                    select n["OrderResult" ].ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
        return query;
    }

    public DataTable OrderResults()
    {

                DataTable dt = new DataTable("OrderResults");
                DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("OrderNumber", typeof(System.Int32));
                dt.Columns.Add(dc);
                dc = new DataColumn("OrderResult", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add(dc);

                for(int i=1; i<10; i++)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr["OrderNumber"] = i;
                    dr["OrderResult"] =i +" Result";
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }

                return dt;
    }


    public DataTable OrderNumbers()
    {

                DataTable dt = new DataTable("OrderNumbers");
                DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("OrderNumber", typeof(System.Int32));
                dt.Columns.Add(dc);

                for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr["OrderNumber"] = i;
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }

                return dt;
    }
```

Comment: Can't you upgrade to .Net 4.0? It contains many improvements to multithreading.

Comment: Upgrading is not possible yet for my old projects.

Comment: You might want to look into [how to change your method to run async](http://www.csharp-examples.net/create-asynchronous-method/) or possibly just using the thread pool to run the content of your `for` async.

Comment: I see you've made an edit. Did my solution not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If .NET 4.0 is available you can just use the Parallel.ForEach construct.

If not, processing this in parallel is as simple as using the `ThreadPool` class, with some additional work for synchronization:

```
int tasks = 0; // keep track of number of active tasks
object locker = new object(); // synchronization object

foreach(var order1 in dtOrders.AsEnumerable())
{
    lock(locker) tasks++; // added a new task
    var order = order1; // local copy to avoid data races
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
       o =>
       {          
            string orderNumber = order["OrderNumber"].ToString();
            string orderResult = SearchResultByOrderNumber(orderNumber);
            DataRow dr = dtResult.NewRow();
            dr["OrderNumber"] = orderNumber;
            dr["OrderResult"] = orderResult;

            lock(locker) // update shared data structure and signal termination
            {
                dtResult.Rows.Add(dr);
                tasks--;
                Monitor.Pulse(locker);
            }                
       });
}

// barrier to wait for all tasks to finish
lock(locker)
{
   while(tasks > 0) Monitor.Wait(locker); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I am going to try. But I must achieve this with .NET 3.5

Comment: @Todor: Sorry for late response. It is working great.. Now I am getting the results in half of the normal time. Now Instead of DataTable, I am trying to insert the records into MS-SQL DB with the format of dtResult DataTable. How can I manage this with the ThreadPool ?

Comment: With SqlAdapter I can insert the DataTable to db. Thank you

Comment: I have change my this console project to windows project. Now windows is not responding while querying with thread.sleep(4000) How can I solve this ? thank you. Do I need to ask new question ?

Comment: @qods: Which thread are you running the code on? The UI thread?

Comment: yes, I think UI thread. I create WindowsForm project. I am using this code in WF project.

Comment: @qods: You are probably blocking the UI thread since you are waiting for the workers to finish. You should delegate your code to a `BackgroundWorker` in order to not block the UI.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`CountdownEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent.aspx) which will block the current thread, until the count is 0:

```
var sync = new object();
var cd = new CountDownEvent(dtOrders.Rows.Count);

foreach(var order in dtOrders)
{
    var dr = dtResult.NewRow();
    dr["OrderNumber"] = order["OrderNumber"].ToString();

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => 
    {
        dr["OrderResult"] = SearchResultByOrderNumber(dr["OrderNumber"].ToString());

        lock(sync) dtResult.Rows.Add(dr);
        cd.Signal();
    });
}

cd.Wait();
```

- The count value is set in the constructor.
- `cd.Signal()` decrement the count by one.
- `cd.Wait()` blocks the current thread until count is 0.

Comment: Thank you ebb, I am going to try.