# running tasks parallely in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, parallel.foreach

By seeing this solution specified in [Divide Foreach into threads sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899649/divide-foreach-into-threads-sample)

I tried to implement it with this code:

```
foreach (Object vo in arrreclist)
{
    msg = String.Empty;
    objprocess.GetType().GetMethod("ProcessRecord").Invoke(objprocess, new Object[] { vo });

    status = (StatusInfo)objprocess.GetType().GetProperty("status").GetValue(objprocess, null);
    if (status.errcode != 0)
    {
        lngfailedcnt++;
        WriteErrorLog();
    }
    else
    {
        lngsuccesscnt++;
        lngInstanceSuccCount++;
    }
    lngcnt++;
    if ((lngcnt % 10) == 0)
    {

        if (instanceId == 0)
        {
            schldr.ModifyJobhistoryForUploadFileRecCnt(Runid, (int)lngTotreccnt, lngfailedcnt, (int)(lngfailedcnt + lngsuccesscnt));
        }
        else
        {
            schldr.ModifyJobhistoryForUploadFileRecCnt(Runid, 0, lngfailedcnt, (int)(lngfailedcnt + lngsuccesscnt));
        }
        status = schldr.status;
        if (status.errcode != 0)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Errorlogfile))
                WriteErrorLog();
            holdInstance = true;
            break;
        }
        //Get Job Status
        //If job was terminated then Update Batch and Job history with status as STOPPED
        intstatus = schedulersvc.GetJobStatus(Runid);
        status = schedulersvc.status;
        if (status.errcode != 0)
        {
            WriteErrorLog();
            holdInstance = true;
            break;
        }
        if (intstatus == 1) //STOPPED
        {
            holdInstance = true;
            break;
        }
        lngcnt = 0;
    }
}
```

And  error message is coming for break statement:

> cannot leave the body of anonymous method or lambda expression

My major task is to parallelize  the following line:

```
objprocess.GetType().GetMethod("ProcessRecord").Invoke(objprocess, new Object[] { vo })
```

But other are dependents so how to implement?

Comment: First of all why are you using Reflection? Instead why don't you define an interface & Use Parallel.ForEach

Comment: Your error does not match with the code you posted: I don't see any lambdas there.

Comment: Also, when you say that you want to parallelize only that line, does that mean the rest of the loop can't run in parallel?

Comment: @svick i didnot post the parallelized code in the post and also thinking about using parallel.foreach to make above code run parallel but array list is not supported, and i think status is not thread safe as it taking status of objprocess in loop,so what might be an alternative way,and coming to line, as that particular line invokes a method which takes more time so i want to run it parallel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, parallelization often doesn't make sense in ASP.NET. If you have many users accessing your site, you usually care more about scalability (how many users can you serve at the same time), than raw performance for single user.

If that's not your case, parallelization might make sense for you.

Second, you're getting that error, because `Parallel.ForEach()` is not a loop (as far as the language is concerned). And `break`ing out of a lambda doesn't make any sense.

To break out of `Parallel.ForEach()`, you can use [`ParallelLoopState.Break()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate.break.aspx) or [`ParallelLoopState.Stop()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate.stop.aspx) (read the documentation to find out which one of those do you actually want). To do this, you will need to use an overload of `Parallel.ForEach()` that gives you that `ParallelLoopState`.

Third, there is a good reason why `Parallel.ForEach()` doesn't support `ArrayList`: it's because you should never use it. If you really want a list of `object`s, use `List<object>` to make it clear that you really don't know the type. If you can't (or don't want to) change the `ArrayList`, you can use `.Cast<object>()` to make `Parallel.ForEach()` (and other methods that work with `IEnumerable<T>`) accept it.

Fourth, I think that parallelizing just the `ProcessRecord` doesn't make sense. It looks like `status` returns the status for the last `ProcessRecord`. And if you execute `ProcessRecord` in parallel, then it's not clear anymore which one is the last.

Also, you shouldn't *think* that some method is not thread-safe. You should know that. If you parallelize something that you don't know is thread-safe, you're likely to get hard to debug bugs later on.

Fifth, if you want to parallelize just the first part of a loop, I think the best option is PLINQ. Something like:

```
var intermediateResults = source.AsParallel().Select(x => Process(x));

foreach (var intermediateResult in intermediateResults)
{
    // the rest of the loop
}
```